# High value for SD for data in range -100 to +250?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, scipy

I Have a 1D data . I am trying to approximate this data to a gaussian distribution.  I want to use MLE to estimate the parameters.

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def gaussian(params):
        mean = params[0]   
        sd = params[1]
    
        # Calculate negative log likelihood
        nll = -np.sum(stats.norm.logpdf(error, loc=mean, scale=sd))
    
        return nll
    
    
    initparam = [1.0, 1.0]
    
    results = minimize(gaussian, initparam, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

The data is outcome of an experiment , constrained between -100. to  +250.

The output of  is
[40.69322685 59.63110135]. I understand the mean, looks ok.

But Why SD is 59.63?

```
32.21825012
-3.250185974
10.70638863
2.654302294
-1.105566299
7.129903787
15.77742559
43.13988574
75.32340854
124.4365483
122.6741832
176.1337512
229.7261925
226.6041901
173.3167507
144.3041021
97.59299378
95.01547968
90.08419156
92.06107865
81.32404177
72.98644313
39.3423542
46.94100995
26.57639928
35.098755
9.057653422
0.686536581
1.644338009
7.051411922
12.02451138
25.7810709
101.1666195
134.4616082
136.5921682
136.6606376
148.7934806
100.6463137
134.5367104
77.36525528
-61.63223954
18.67617437
28.24676204
-20.62251866
-2.70792451
-15.89578422
-4.763700612
0.942246613
3.604620803
3.604841812
0.604051511
16.91794831
57.26864359
142.1342027
59.85451277
-13.31761828
83.62986809
44.33392214
110.6736618
47.80192341
55.69949416
67.41821892
228.2539849
165.9799694
70.01332855
51.02973621
23.59563609
31.22465043
31.04057176
12.46498353
2.099227287
-0.421296255
2.243410264
23.70235318
73.0653426
172.3894995
57.43889091
11.03017949
57.62986809
87.49264588
66.05667249
59.67366177
87.69949416
97.28390414
169.052553
55.79355733
105.0993763
52.78311439
32.08325825
4.216297211
-5.361930625
1.112042102
1.997004674
4.800753077
25.53724673
82.17166229
131.9851823
-25.16368611
4.921855055
-19.21216812
3.533143877
7.517772967
74.41616809
77.15709787
214.4928143
222.8468688
188.5267283
97.77279729
33.84693314
4.455576976
5.108158148
14.58567243
3.478565029
3.885168254
-1.705070485
5.411239465
15.4673322
39.0390347
126.0120806
240.6444946
19.24757388
19.12624845
38.82460163
34.11311076
76.229195
43.30565539
88.11035467
107.8104678
154.368652
51.29648991
54.75949317
69.48707106
42.31133439
16.19876379
14.47435382
3.540656334
1.392292582
6.167364337
4.897147373
0.552225026
104.1260843
34.38803022
87.54064449
29.60390951
66.01683418
44.69929961
51.57580757
45.63776059
122.6706773
157.1438708
174.228822
141.6901068
128.9271561
163.2634713
26.02236789
83.73525127
57.911791
41.15660171
45.16874146
28.2226258
6.461993391
4.186022743
-0.964221675
3.761311768
8.015955119
30.44173885
89.62947117
102.8308413
218.4714017
247.5273446
159.2888365
132.6117347
117.9785682
104.4926764
132.4767572
77.97926907
82.74644033
46.27809992
36.00334599
29.74973299
22.67982924
3.657292696
-0.732946685
-5.577275615
-7.815636423
10.61177483
12.03413813
19.91398825
59.85610892
93.55918396
97.10967695
33.18591234
124.5604134
145.7757955
117.7636455
91.76806769
23.77590013
40.24407347
24.32536624
20.83451673
2.615208246
4.968765606
-5.526690268
-0.429689387
-0.439905174
7.320620611
6.122387439
42.33518403
43.90587608
204.0412224
50.55163848
9.44971704
70.2699496
119.9706338
171.0293463
61.28863429
78.41805554
104.1565127
134.5723288
90.98116214
94.59757547
1.359567672
26.20788259
5.345014524
-3.43463697
-4.941142273
-0.676023085
3.922050326
22.90661171
21.13414192
106.506427
74.33117323
15.09067175
32.38526665
29.24304559
78.51361589
27.53646784
84.12920254
133.1167026
208.7495614
153.1075959
209.8104678
60.75921597
43.23804459
2.566266154
-8.848688829
1.472074927
6.078736361
3.495580384
6.399596843
0.338237902
13.71356207
31.08256062
97.50354626
206.9395617
23.75005172
-1.450408776
31.66482714
33.20119984
69.229195
55.70423856
46.55497197
105.8104678
169.54673
149.8728483
178.8104678
71.75921597
37.48479751
19.38605299
7.854814264
4.312805097
8.320534067
2.248662504
-1.441027981
4.081264857
10.41002846
21.86948069
120.123634
221.0419093
67.13935424
26.92319681
47.94145063
74.92981477
101.0364813
71.08991162
97.52637082
182.8104678
159.0055111
75.00551111
124.8104678
44.75921597
49.797334
44.63973896
33.76849205
18.10283056
12.17927581
1.724695591
8.165863649
6.406568497
11.54510627
57.92839524
80.71811403
202.0697865
128.6123088
61.89995091
72.89899651
70.66526401
144.0685655
109.9607677
111.3690798
192.1167026
225.2497094
55.07886006
95.81046779
25.88047528
8.978071369
36.78696248
52.24575758
17.9401072
29.80160395
28.61876981
10.35926293
0.656953295
-3.184320407
0.209309305
25.79997418
34.64763363
128.1631316
38.1135818
131.8158459
145.2339419
145.9858012
107.3898159
120.4069296
96.19117774
16.30135532
25.72270338
51.3231413
66.06707935
68.96594905
47.12522479
12.3330931
33.40295837
27.64204364
41.64887033
19.55663001
3.626273384
1.68617336
-6.60428966
-0.252477628
0.614054858
41.62375959
69.26882767
106.5145031
188.3840883
101.6703619
55.35070889
102.5413617
165.3450653
15.28617201
-65.75878483
-20.13482242
20.84622526
35.59743606
15.39137214
-19.74644475
7.195753799
4.670953817
-0.427945057
-1.069996734
0.824311266
1.85325265
23.65965242
66.82316953
190.0357789
33.50660427
2.633454805
36.91351384
53.49150527
50.77734997
21.77734997
50.54418132
238.8943844
108.0729022
-0.140173987
-33.68503696
-55.47798556
9.160836067
-6.399628893
4.15240465
1.253685844
0.651323931
3.172168148
13.40434764
32.2300657
99.51443953
239.9007906
74.25045735
34.68238172
104.7872615
109.4541127
75.51777297
36.53314388
35.43154638
82.62213648
188.5696577
120.5208153
128.1167026
71.01132072
3.95290406
25.10772189
9.19501676
12.73703391
1.376186687
-1.869255153
1.50043361
3.25495252
8.469127585
22.85971547
111.6037199
78.78059048
25.13963712
52.72288009
12.2454257
10.23353572
15.23353572
33.68027357
69.81938395
169.8795512
168.7591407
111.1167026
45.13683161
5.174670743
20.53261803
20.11155396
9.486206728
5.208818849
1.885951193
0.222336513
2.00590324
11.98356921
19.28090076
85.22775303
117.3457878
67.68831007
22.13963712
52.00226975
11.53990705
48.57580757
44.12771007
68.5921215
78.81046779
85.23383868
25.21300282
39.28457371
-22.82259107
-41.9749672
-30.61694619
-37.52900118
-4.345063021
-8.671173163
-7.373733389
-1.211168563
2.468495225
0.082843301
23.06147132
18.61170217
181.4136314
74.41585482
48.19822982
56.03713055
87.79190703
133.5343841
112.5343841
156.3815947
161.5664809
178.665223
99.37048347
33.30484147
-7.367047476
-41.90670206
0.644949542
-7.829813652
11.76254446
17.15200881
-4.278076189
-5.895650269
1.17205654
1.954842251
4.454706529
-2.192067744
-11.04076624
51.2738679
16.19453442
59.83667825
44.07913308
55.46211265
58.78222979
49.42175092
45.61207626
14.82776298
-19.50680818
-34.06078737
23.65120321
14.60331813
2.87448579
6.22730126
6.566502979
2.932277442
-5.141225396
-4.19118898
-0.619329705
1.737859072
5.947556553
9.543584541
20.1262535
17.92954755
-1.762726627
46.50222306
103.0635356
93.549155
73.04036976
40.44088979
89.21544564
32.34161595
8.998512322
3.896372475
18.03709275
9.843657365
27.66035117
-2.439169648
-5.866172598
2.196122244
1.549335442
0.023807975
-2.221622012
-34.3164931
-98.0293432
-0.610078704
21.7350195
17.58985937
13.7420181
-10.23195235
-23.09048625
-28.93231968
-83.02871558
-90.17402433
-65.99511363
-39.78217574
-33.63603779
-28.05856801
-15.55394312
-5.773952041
-5.257320067
-6.998056777
-2.89017989
-0.628870541
1.5470415
-12.44338942
-20.38299955
-4.725318404
-47.28327538
5.587433788
27.48565234
-30.80170459
-5.416250968
-4.334665209
-24.89730622
-48.52744598
-46.97354523
-39.07731723
3.179182053
-1.070027433
-14.39954749
1.965145981
-11.95790516
-3.978019729
-3.116741005
-0.727416069
-0.611778787
3.519328911
-12.36683397
-33.02194277
-35.47367609
-38.81345032
-34.43600171
-28.34449343
-31.06514909
-28.16409421
-35.06313224
-36.59633513
-3.547677452
-32.60441298
-13.32689569
-17.6986153
-84.0502597
-21.35936715
-19.29615056
-10.02116977
-4.363841357
-2.61929041
-2.106998313
0.201290503
-1.346470635
-2.556374932
-91.92876767
-32.46449623
-28.99036708
-1.148734035
-21.46807235
11.37675088
14.39300563
15.10626388
56.30619467
117.2877839
56.49439309
29.25493642
4.257285166
-13.41378215
-5.30812978
-7.054321948
-2.53647735
-4.245541463
-1.751762638
-1.335960924
0.487997738
2.127952855
3.094671162
-68.80387851
-53.14620722
31.12525843
58.66904727
73.21466464
90.76241834
113.1527931
152.1527931
112.7691374
128.0359593
137.4845255
78.49271215
39.3888566
10.17918713
14.75045241
14.60184505
18.75627582
3.661478276
15.75746324
-6.774831119
-5.831553694
-1.071719144
-0.970194398
-0.992727273
-4.975367731
8.71715482
11.55129472
-51.28075683
-20.68617212
-13.25975884
20.41269964
3.763474491
33.40599728
46.71414299
16.7630538
11.84784049
12.62139434
28.43104769
25.86272034
21.1106172
-0.541738074
14.63211887
9.491119566
-9.677008582
0.186816056
3.028257979
-1.804655046
3.959007946
0.627968459
0.696023418
39.78319809
24.52347216
37.37758091
44.87222625
71.89212016
64.18373189
40.01193977
33.79113882
24.65273671
21.2244114
45.80669141
34.3609385
12.33719389
8.365946373
27.71354343
16.81882269
11.05385648
7.475024685
-1.869519857
0.020447986
-0.965772374
-11.28667832
-33.63709383
-65.91393195
2.743369153
54.50282163
88.70481939
112.775024
97.75362986
141.3764233
208.9488336
96.30619467
38.15650136
-9.511135837
3.673239444
-26.01052504
-19.04838752
-6.98530056
4.177146983
```

Comment: You may want to have a comparator method to check your results, maybe using [`pd.DataFrame(my_array).describe()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255011/16327476).  Also, to help others help you, maybe provide a fully self-contained snippet that they can run, including a mini toy dataset.  Toy dataset is often a good idea for debugging anyway of course.

Comment: Why not? Why do you consider this to be odd?

Comment: Since the outcome is constrained to [-100, 250], wouldn't you need a truncated gaussian? The SD could decrease, but probably not by much.